# How to hide form fields in twig template?

Tags: forms, symfony, hidden-field

I have a Symfony form that includes two `TextType` fields. If a certain check evaluates to `false`, I don't want to display the `input` fields but output the static content of the field and include the form fields as `hidden` fields instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use `HiddenType`,
or hide field in template:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% if someValue == true %}
        {{ form_widget(form.fieldName) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.fieldName, { 'attr': {'class': 'hidden-row'} }) }}
    {% endif %}
    {# other fields... #}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

or you can use FormEvents like `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` in FormType.
[(doc)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class)

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of switch in `form_row` but I suspect that this is not implemented in Symfony...

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel in fact it is :), I updated my answer

Comment: No, what I meant was not hiding it via CSS, but rendering it as an hidden field. But I saw that your second approach allows that. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

You can prevent any output for the form field by pretending, that it was already rendered:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% if someValue == true %}
        {% do form.fieldName.setRendered() %}
    {% endif %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: That‘s nice to know. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: this is actually I want ;)

Comment: I have one problem; when I use this code and submit form data changed to null but I have data in the form

Comment: Yes, if you have a value for a field and want to keep it you need to use the other approach in this Question. This answer is supposed to remove all traces of the field in the HTML code, which also results in values not being set, when transmitting the form.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Symfony 4.4, you can set the `div style="display: none;" style:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  <div class="row">
    {% if app.user %}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <fieldset>
        Login by: {{ app.user.username }}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <fieldset>
        Mail : {{ app.user.email }}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="display: none;">
      <fieldset>
        {{ form_widget(form.owner, { 'attr': {'class': '', value: 'null'}}) }}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <fieldset>
        {{ form_widget(form.owner, {'attr': {'class': ''}}) }}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <fieldset>
        {{ form_widget(form.content, {'attr': {'class': ''}}) }}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="main-button">New</button>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Please share more details. In your code, there's no condition to check for the other field. Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to understand your answer